# How to download Geoserver Layer Preview ( .GIF) with geoserver rest

Tags: api, rest, geoserver

We can download it manually in the geoserver panel, but the question is how to do it automatically ?

I tried to create the same url as is created in the panel and and send it as GET,POST but it doesn't work.

here is a picture of exactly what i mean:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't. GeoServer's REST api is solely for access and modification of it's configuration.

To download an image from the WMS service you must use the KVP endpoint specified in the GetCapabilities response (linked from the home page).